# Difference between だけで and でだけ?

Tags: word-choice, particles, particle-で

The だけ meaning "only", and で being the "at/in" particle. When saying "only in/at", does the で　come before, or after the だけ? What does it mean, if anything, when it's reversed?

Example: "You can only get this plush toy in Japan". Is it,

> このぬいぐるみを日本だけで手に入れます。

or

> このぬいぐるみを日本でだけ手に入れます。

Side note: does the same principle apply to しか?

Comment: Side note:  Yes, it also applies to しか.  Also to both だけ and しか using に.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The scope of だけ is different depending on where you put it.

- このぬいぐるみを((日本だけ)で)手に入れます。-　"You can get this plush toy in (only Japan)"
- このぬいぐるみを((日本で)だけ)手に入れます。- "You can get this plush toy ((in Japan) only)"

Here it does not seem to show a big difference.

Translating from [this source](http://jp.hjenglish.com/new/p12886/):

> ~だけで is typically used to mean "just this method/location/person will be necessary to accomplish this task"
>   
> While ~でだけ means "only by ~, and no other method, will the task be accomplished"
>   For example,
>
> > その仕事は二人だけでできます - This job only requires 2 persons. (It doesn't need any more people)
> >
> > その仕事は二人でだけできます - This job only requires 2 persons. (No more, no less)

Comment: We don't say `このぬいぐるみを手に入ります。` it should be `このぬいぐるみを手に入れます`　or `このぬいぐるみは（～で）手に入ります`　and these have different meanings.

Comment: @Teno. Ah, thanks for the correction. Is it いれます or はいれます then?

Comment: They read `このぬいぐるみを手に入{い}れます` and `このぬいぐるみは（～で）手に入{はい}ります`