# How to understand ...だけで...できる

Tags: grammar

> 仲間**だけで**歌を楽しむ**ことができます**
>
> ボタンを押す**だけで**いいんです

---

These are sentences which are found in textbook.

I'm confusing in these two sentences.

Here's my understanding.

---

In first sentence.

> You can enjoy Karaoke with your friends, other **people also are allowed**
>
> You can enjoy Karaoke with your friends, other **people are denied**

In second sentence.

> You can press this button, you also **can press other buttons**
>
> You can press this button, you **are not allowed to press other buttons**

Which is the correct way to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仲間だけで歌を楽しむことができます means "You can enjoy Karaoke with only your friends". It means others are not allowed to join in the karaoke.

ボタンを押すだけでいいんです means "You have only to press the button." It doesn't refer to whether you can press other buttons or not.

If you want to mean …した(する)だけで…できる, you can use this phrase "just by ～ing". For example, I can tell what you're thinking just by looking at you.(君を見るだけで、何を考えてるのか分かる).

Comment: I just found another answer about だけで https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/7027/29959, it says other situations could be exist if somebody is saying だけで. For example, その仕事は2人だけでできます, which means two people can finish this job, but more people can do this job too.

Comment: Why is *not allowed* in sentence 1?

Comment: Because だけ means "only". 仲間だけで means "with only my(your) friends", not including others.