# 「大分違う」in this sentence

Tags: meaning

Taken from the first book of 「働く魔王さま」

Context: A girl is having a talk with her friend about having a buzzing in her ear and lately hearing voices mingled with this buzzing. These voices are warning her about catastrophes that might happen in the future. At the conclusion of their conversation her friend says:

> 「幸いその耳鳴りの主も悪意で接触してきてるわけではないみたいだし、いざというとき自分の周りの人に注意を**促せる**だけで**大分違う**と思うよ」

I already checked out this question about the differences of 「だけで」 and 「でだけ」 ([Difference between だけで and でだけ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7026/difference-between-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91). On jisho 促せる is listed as potential and I used this definition of 大分: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%A7%E5%88%86.

What I am really struggling with here is the last part of 「大分違う」.  I first interpreted this statement with some kind of "positive" intend of the speaker in the sense of: "When it gets dangerous you are able to warn the people around you, what will make a big difference"; however I feel something is wrong here and after checking several definitions of 「違う」 I figured that these "positive" aspects are not necessarily mentioned there. In accordance with that I think this sentence rather means: "Being able to warn the people around you when it gets dangerous is unusual enough". However, I feel like this interpretation is missing something.

Therefore, my question is whether you can interpret inherent "positivity" into this sentence or not.

Can 「違う」 have this meaning of changing a certain siuation? (I found a defintion of 「違う」saying it was equal to　「たがう」)

Please let me know if I am completely off with both interpretations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "positivity" can be inferred from the statement because of「促せる」and the strongness of the positivity can be inferred from 「大分」.

As you said,「せる」is the potential. From the context,「促せる」seems to imply that a good thing (i.e. to warn the people around the speaker) would not be possible if the speaker didn't hear the voices.

Even if「大分」were not used、positivity would not disappear. However,「大分」is more than sufficient and reflects the speaker's admiration.

「十分違う」would be used if the speaker meant "unusual enough".

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I just have one follow-up question: Is there a specific reason why 「十分」has this different meaning? I think I got the main difference between both of these words, but somehow cannot explain their (true) meaning difference.

Comment: Does 大分 really have such a positive meaning on its own? If it were 結構違う, かなり違う, 割と違う or 相当違う, the sentence would roughly mean the same. But I agree that 促せるだけで is expected to be followed by something positive.

Comment: @Himula The main concept of「十分」is sufficiency (similar to「充分」), while that of「大分」is the largeness of amount.

Comment: @naruto It doesn't. 「大分」on its own means just the largeness of the amount.「結構」,「かなり」,「割と」and「相当」are all related to the level of amount. They are particularly used when the amount is larger than the speaker's hidden expectation.

Comment: えーとそういうことではなく、回答の冒頭に、"The positivity can be inferred because of 大分" とあるのが引っかかっています。この「大分」は単純に程度を表しているだけであり、これがあろうとなかろうと、あるいは「ちょっと」や「凄く」や「十分」だろうと、文章の positivity が反転する訳ではないのでは、という話です。ネガティブな意味にするなら「大分おかしいと思うよ」「大分変だと思うよ」のように「違う」の方を変えることになると思います。細かくてすみません。

Comment: @naruto 確かにその通りですね。positivityは「大分」がなくても消えませんね。「大分」とわざわざいっていることから、直感的にpositivityが結構強いということが感じられると思うので、文の全体的なpositivityを高めることには役立っているように感じます。