# what's the meaning of "心の中だけで笑わない"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, words, expressions

I have seen this sentence in a japanese tv show.
I think it should mean:`“only in your heart, you don't laugh.”`
But the right explanation is,

> “Don't just laugh in your heart ”

(by the way it tells you that "`Do not just feel laughter in your heart, but express it outwardly`.)
I still don't understand even search many websites.
there is the same(maybe?) sentence:

> 口だけで行動しない

it means:`“only talk and no action”`
why there has the difference between this two sentences?
And what's the meaning of the above sentence?

> 心の中だけで笑わない

I would be appreciate it if someone can tell me.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The で in the first sentence is a particle denoting a place where some action happens and, judging from the translation, the sentence was said as a negative imperative sentence. (It would sound weird as a statement.)

It can be understood as:

> 心の中**だけで**笑わない（＝笑うな）。
> Don’t laugh **only in** your heart.

This implies you should laugh in other places as well.

The で in the second, on the other hand, is a copula as 口だけ stands as a predicate by itself.

> （彼は）口だけだ。
> He is all talk (*lit.* He is only the mouth).

This is combined with another independent sentence（彼は）行動しない, which just happens to be a negative statement.

> （彼は）口だけで（あって）、行動しない。
> He is all talk and doesn’t act.

Comment: A follow-up question: I would interpret （自分が）心の中だけで笑わない, instead of the negative-imperative. I'd expect the imperative to be 笑わない**で**. What gives the hint that this isn't "Only within my heart I cannot laugh"? (※  I know you're native speaker so you're correct, just wanted to know why)

Comment: @dvx2718 - That would be 心の中（で）だけ笑わない. Here ない simply denies 笑う with 心の中（で）だけ working on 笑わない. In the original, ない denies the whole of 心の中だけで笑う and it sounds weird as a statement. [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/7026/43676) seems related.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see